# Sequence number for each different value in a colum

Tags: google-sheets

I have an *Input* column with a sequence of two different letters. As result I want to get something like on the picture. This formulas I will use with `ARRAYFORMULA` to get unlimited count of rows. To get *BLOCK №* I was trying to use `=COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,"N")` but it works only if I copy the formula manually down the column, but if I do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(($B$2):(B2:B),"N"))
```

It doesn't work.

How can I replicate the behavior of this function without needed to manually copy it?

[image: Table Example]

Comment: Here is a test sheet [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jU4obzZUv4sr4JPe3ha8XDSl51j9o-4jVsXFxSxW8BY/edit?usp=sharing]. Now the question is how to make `=index(H:H,max(isnumber(H$2:H2)*row(H$2:H2)))` possible to use with `ARRAYFORMULA`

Comment: Or how to repeat `=MAX(H$2:H2)` for each row with `ARRAYFORMULA` and put instead _H**2**_ current _No_ of row

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing a script to fill the Block Nos.

I'll assume the topmost letter begins at cell `input!A4` and you want the Block Nos from cell `input!C5` and below. Go to the menu bar of the spreadsheet and select Script Editor. Then write the following scripts:

```js
//the main function
function writeBlocks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('input');
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 4;
  var inputCol = 1;
  var outputCol = 3;
  var block = 0;

  //clear old Block Nos
  sheet.getRange(startRow, outputCol, numRows - 3, 1)
    .clearContent();

  //recalculate LastRow in case there are fewer new inputs than old outputs
  numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  //get input data
  var input = sheet.getRange(startRow, inputCol, numRows - 3, 1)
    .getValues;

  //write output data
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    block += input[i] == "N" ? 1 : 0;
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, outputCol)
      .setValue(block);
  }
}

//create new menu
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Calculate blocks", functionName: "writeBlocks"});
  ss.addMenu("Custom functions", menuEntries);
}
```

Save it all, refresh the spreadsheet, and there should be a new option on the menu bar. When you select that option, it will clear the old Block Nos and generate new ones based on the current inputs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I get error when try run script TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetByName in object function getActiveSpreadsheet() {/* */}. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: My mistake, I left out a pair of parentheses in the getActiveSpreadsheet() method. Have edited my post to correct it. Hope it works now.

Comment: Now it is goes without errors but I did't get any results. Actually I found another way how to get _Block Nos_ without scripts. In cell B4 `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(R2:R="N",1,""))` it will put in each row with "N" - "1" and in cell C4: `=arrayFormula(IF(R2:R<>"",(if(isBlank(P2:P),ifError(1/0),sumif(row(P2:P),"<=" & row(P2:P),P2:P))),""))` it will sum row B4 up to current position.

Comment: Here is a test sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jU4obzZUv4sr4JPe3ha8XDSl51j9o-4jVsXFxSxW8BY/edit?usp=sharing. Now the question is how to make `=index(H:H,max(isnumber(H$2:H2)*row(H$2:H2)))` possible to use with `ARRAYFORMULA`